# How to enforce tagging while S3 bucket creation in member account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to enforce particular tagging while creating S3 buckets in member account but unable to enforce as its still allows me to create S3 without tag even though below policy in place.

[scp-policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Nmu.png)

Also If I make it "Resource": "*" or "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*", I am not able to create S3 with or without tag (It just deny creation of s3). Only the option seen in snap works but its not preventing when I dont give "user" tag

Comment: Please include policies, code fragments etc. inline in text, not in external images.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to supply tags when creating an S3 bucket using the S3 [CreateBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html) API, so you cannot enforce tagging at creation time. You'd have to implement some reactive process, e.g. scan buckets periodically to ensure proper tagging.

Comment: I think there is option to give tags when creating bucket from console

Comment: The S3 console's create bucket feature does allow you to indicate tags and it also allows you to indicate versioning, block public access, encryption, object lock and more at the 'same time'. It's providing this as a convenience to you while under the covers it is actually invoking multiple S3 API calls on your behalf, the first of which is CreateBucket. It will then invoke [PutBucketTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketTagging.html) and other API calls, as needed. However, you cannot supply tags on a CreateBucket API call so you cannot enforce tagging.